# Chanting Mantra for variety of Pooja's on different gods

Tags: mantras, puja, stotra

While doing the Festival Pooja in home, I am always Chanting the mantra Vishnu Sahasranamam while doing Arathi for all festivals. Hence Could someone please help me to learn mantras for different types of festivals like, Ganesh Chaturthi, Diwali Festival, Pongal Festival (Surya God's), Pradosham and Skandha shasti etc...

Comment: Do u need sahsranamas for all deities or only ashtottaras will do?Also mantras are to be obtained only from a Guru.In other cases u can recite simple stutis that praise the Deities.

Comment: @Rickross: Only "Suklambaratharam...." upto three to four pages we are chanting.

Comment: During aratis usually bhajans(songs) are sung.If u want stotrams then there are many for each Deity like, kanda shasti kavacham(if u know tamil),Kumarashtakam etc(for Skanda),Shiva Pradosha Mahima stotram(for Shiva),Ganesha Shodasha nama stotram or Ganesha sankata nasana stotram(for Ganapaty),Aditya Hridayam,Suryastkam etc for Surya.For Diwali Mahalakshmi ashtakam etc.

Comment: @Rickross: Could you please provide samples...

Comment: Samples of aratis:http://www.drikpanchang.com/lyrics/aarti/aarti-collection.html...  Few stotrams :http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Pradosha_Mahima...  http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Skanda_Sashti_Kavacham...  http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Ganesa_Shodasa_Nama_stotram

Comment: @ssr1012-Vishnu sahasranama you chant without arthi. While showing arthi recite three slokas from rama mangalam.  Mangalam kosalendraya  ---

Answer (score 1):

Vishnu sahasranama you chant without arthi. Aftedr finishing sahasranam While showing arthi recite three slokas from rama mangalam.  Mangalam kosalendraya  ---      For ganesh chaturthi   vinayaka ashthotra namavali     for    Deepavali    Lakshmi Ashtagam and Ashthothiram      for Pongal   festival  Aaditya Hudyam  for   Pradosham   Sivan stotrams or Lakshmi narasimha ashtagam  /runa  vomohana narasimha stotram / mattapalli mangalashtagam /mantra raja pada stotram   and for kantha sashti      kantha sashti kavacham, sathru sangara vel pathigam/aru padai veedugal stotrams